# Hiding a div on Mouse click out OR escape keyword press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that hides my div (live search results) when mouse is clicked outside the div but I can't incorporate an OR function that does the same thing (hides div) when the escape key is pressed. Any help is much, much appreciated. Also, original code on mouse click out is from a different thread I got here on Stackoverflow. The or function is giving me a hard time.

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.form_content').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if $('#display').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hides #display on pressing escape:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.which === 27) {
        $('#display').hide();
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nsufH/

You could also try to use **window instead of document**:

```
$(window).keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.which === 27) {
        $('#display').hide();
    }
});
```

Or try to use **live**:

```
$(document).live('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.which === 27) {
        $('#display').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before also and with your code but it still won't work for some odd reason.

Comment: Is it in your document.ready? When does the #display exist? Use .on or .live

Comment: Did you put this in your $(document).ready(function(){ ? I posted an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nsufH/

Comment: Thanks so much Fabian. I'm gonna mess around with your code for a while and post an update.

Comment: Hey Fabian, so here's my problem. When I am searching and try to click escape, the script doesn't work and it doesn't hide my live search results. If however, I search then click out of the search box and try to press escape, it hides my results. Again, forget about the mouseout function, when I disable the mousout function and use the escape script only, I HAVE to clickout of the form field that I'm typing in and then press escape in order for it to properly hide the div. Any help?

Comment: You can try to use this: $("#ID_of_input_field").keyup( .. Otherwise can you provide a link to a live example?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to monitor for the KeyCode and act based off it:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { $('#display').hide() }   // esc
});
```

Comment: it should work (http://api.jquery.com/event.which/). Also tested: http://jsfiddle.net/nsufH/

Comment: Drahkar this only works when I switch to keydown (I have to hold it down obviously). I'm typing in an input field if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseup keyup', function(e){ 
        var e = e || event,
         code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which),
       target = e.srcElement || e.target;

        if (target.className != 'form_content' || code==27) {
            $('#display').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Adeneo, I have to click out of the form that I'm typing in then click escape in order for this code to work.

Comment: @user1011713 Not sure why that happens, code==27 should fire no matter what element the target is, but I would think that it is your input box that does not bubble the keyup event to the document level. Try adding your input element to the code above, stick the input element in with the document on the keyup function to see if it works then.

Comment: Also, you could try replacing keyup with keydown to see if that solves it, or even go all out and try keypress. You should also check if there are any return false statements in regard to the input box you are typing in, or you could try adding the change event to the events map to see if that works.

Comment: So on keyup nothing happens, on keypress nothing happens, on keydown it hides the div but if I keep holding it still. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the #display element disappears on keydown, but shows up again when releasing the button, it's basicly working, so you probably have another function that is firing off a return false or preventing delegation of the keyup event since that's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsfiddle hiding a div on mouseout and ESC key press : 
http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2k6/q2kNX/

Of course there is probably some stuff to do in the way to adapt it as your own source code..